# printing fibonacci from input number

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

So I tried printing Fibonacci sequence using an `input` number. I'm not sure how to input a number into my code.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a,b=0,1
    while(a<n):
        print(a,end=' ')
        a,b=b,a+b
    print()

fibonacci(fibo_entry=input("enter number"))
```

I get this Error:

```
TypeError                                                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-113-d552685b93df> in <module>()
       7         a,b=b,a+b
       8     print()
    ----> 9 fibonacci(fibo_entry=input("enter number"))

    TypeError: fibonacci() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fibo_entry'
```

Answer (score 4):

The `TypeError` is because your function doesn't take an `fibo_entry`-argument. You could call it like this:

```
fibonacci(input("enter number"))
```

However this will give you another error because the `input` always returns a string on python3, so you need to cast it to a number:

```
import ast
fibonacci(ast.literal_eval(input("enter number")))
```

or explicitly:

```
fibonacci(int(input("enter number")))
```

However I would recommend catching the input as seperate variable and just pass that variable to the function:

```
fibo_entry = int(input("enter number"))
fibonacci(fibo_entry)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.! The explicit method worked and seems simple.

Comment: @KrithikaKrishnan No problem. Please don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)/upvote helpful answers. :)

Comment: Hi @KrithikaKrishnan *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, please consider to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you, and increases the chances you'll get good answers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In this line, the python interpreter thinks you are trying to specify an argument for `fibonacci`.

```
fibonacci(fibo_entry=input("enter number"))
```

Easiest fix is to separate it out. You also must cast as an `int`, because input returns a string:

```
fibo_entry=int(input("enter number"))
fibonacci(fibo_entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use typecasting for your 'input' function,
do like this:

```
num=int(input("enter number: "))
fibonacci(num)
```

OR do like this:

```
fibonacci(int(input("enter number: ")))
```